# Does the mergMK module for LiveCode require an internet connection to function?

Tags: livecode

I have an app using google maps on android, which works even if there no internet connection - it records the route but the map is blank until a connection is made/resumed. If I use mergMK with LiveCode to create a similar App for iOS, will it work the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mergMK is just Apple Maps/MapKit so it will behave the same way as the Apple Maps app while offline. In a quick test I did it appears to render maps that are already cached and show a blank areas elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there  a version that uses Google Maps, or is Apple maps not tied to the Apple Map?

Comment: No, MapKit is Apple Maps only since iOS 5